# OpenAPI 3 Dictionary Define Key & Value Types

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have read https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/, but am still having trouble modeling something like:

```json
{
  "top": {
    "elem0": {
      ...
    },
    "elem1": {
      ...
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

`top` is a dictionary, containing an arbitrary number of entries. The trouble is that I want to define a reusable schema for the key and value types.

E.g., instead of saying that the keys are of type `string`, I say they are of type `#/components/schemas/KEY`. And instead of saying that the values are of type `object`, I say they are of type `#/components/schemas/VALUE`.

Is this possible?

Comment: This might help https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/2294.